# Trouble writing 's into a .txt file, using FileOutputStream

Tags: java, file, fileoutputstream

The problem is that when I read a string and then, try to write each characters in separate line, into a `.txt` file, although `System.out.println` will show correct characters, when I write them into a `.txt` file, for the `'s` it will write some weird characters instead. To illustrate, here is an example: suppose we have this line `Second subject’s layout of same 100 pages.` and we want to write it into a `.txt` file, using the following code:

```
public static void write(String Swrite) throws IOException {
   if(!file.exists()){
     file.createNewFile();
   }
   FileOutputStream fop=new FileOutputStream(file,true);

   if(Swrite!=null)
   for(final String s : Swrite.split(" ")){
     fop.write(s.toLowerCase().getBytes());
     fop.write(System.getProperty("line.separator").getBytes());
   }     
   fop.flush();
   fop.close();       
}
```

the written file would look like this for the word, `subject's`: `subjectâ€™s`. I have no idea why this happens.

Comment: Character encoding. You can wrap an OutputStream in an OutputStreamWriter and specify the Charset in that. I don't know what you're using to read the file, but that should support the same character encoding. For example, write in UTF-8 and open it in Notepad++ (if using Windows)

Comment: pass a `Charset` parameter to the method `getByte()`

Comment: @Romski but how to write in `UTF-8`? and yes, when I open it in notepad, it shows something like that. and surely I use a `BufferedReader` to read from file. is it necessary to place the reading code in the question as well?

Comment: @tony200910041 how to do so?

Comment: @lonesome Java string are encoded in UTF-16. So as others have mentioned you need to specify the charset you want for the `getBytes` method. E.g. `s.toLowerCase().getBytes("UTF-8")` should work if you want it encoded as UTF-8.

Comment: java.io.OutputStreamWriter constructor takes an OutputStream (e.g. FileOutputStream) and a number of different ways of specifying a character encoding - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/ -

Answer (score 0):

Try something like the following. It frees you from having to deal with character encoding.

```
PrintWriter pw = null;

try {
  pw = new PrintWriter(file);

  if (Swrite!=null)
    for (String s : Swrite.split(" ")) {
      pw.println(s);
    }
  }
}
finally {
  if (pw != null) {
    pw.close();
  }
}
```

Comment: but your code has two problems. first it will rewrite into existing file which results to only containing last line. second, it will not write in lower case.

Comment: It is only a portion of all the code you need. If you want to delete the file; you need to add the code. If you want to lower case the fstring you need to add the code. I was highlighting how to avoid the call to `getBytes` and problems with character encoding.

Comment: i didnt ask to delete the file, but to `append` the file, so all the string will be included in the final version of the file and not only the last line. but unlike `fileoutputstream` , i see no argument for printwriter to make the file appended.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like this:

```
// The file to read the input from and write the output to.
// Original content: Second subject’s layout of same 100 pages.
File file = new File("C:\\temp\\file.txt");
// The charset of the file, in our case UTF-8.
Charset utf8Charset = Charset.forName("UTF-8");

// Read all bytes from the file and create a string out of it (with the correct charset).
String inputString = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()), utf8Charset);

// Create a list of all output lines
List<String> lines = new ArrayList<>();

// Add the original line and than an empty line for clarity sake.
lines.add(inputString);
lines.add("");

// Convert the input string to lowercase and iterate over it's char array.
// Than for each char create a string which is a new line.
for(char c : inputString.toLowerCase().toCharArray()){
    lines.add(new String(new char[]{c}));
}

// Write all lines in the correct char encoding to the file
Files.write(file.toPath(), lines, utf8Charset);
```

It all has to do with the used charsets as commented above.